# Склонение названия реки с сокращенным родовым наименованием

Tags: грамматика, склонение, названия

Здравствуйте! Имеет ли значение сокращение реки до р. при склонении названия реки? В обоих случаях будет реки Великой и р. Великой? или реки Великой и р. (в смысле реки) Великая? Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В обоих случаях будет "реки Великой" и "р. Великой", если вы не составляете военное донесение или приказ – там географические названия идут в начальной форме.